Where to find specification for .prj files in Natural Earth
I am trying to write my own parser to read Shapefiles, specifically ones from Natural Earth. Right now I'm trying to interpret the .prj files that come with their data. For example, one reads:
GEOGCS[
    "GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM[
        "D_WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]
    ],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
]

I understand that this is some kind of WKT-CRS, but I'm having trouble finding a spec I can follow to understand how to write code to parse this thing.
Specifically, I want to figure out how to actually convert the above into an actual formula/code for mapping (x, y) coordinates in the .shp into actual 3d spherical coordinates.
I found this, but the very oldest version of the standard there states:

If the WKT begins with or contains any of the following keywords, it is an older format:
COMPDCS, FITTED_CS, GEOCCS, GEOGCS, LOCAL_CS, PROJCS, VERT_CS.

so it seems I need an older version for the files I have.

Reinventing this wheel comes with the cost of reverse-engineering the Esri coordinate reference string (which predates WKT by most of a decade).

@Vince So wait, how do systems like QGIS do it? Do they also reverse engineer the format?

Past tense. Did reverse engineer. Many moons in the past.

You might want to have a look at this past SE post. There is no "standard" specification, and the format has mostly evolved from (ironically) different programs attempting to reverse-engineer it.

This is how QGIS and GDAL do it https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogr_srs_esri.cpp.

Like PROJ/QGIS/GDAL, you could look for their WKIDs by checking against the Esri list using one of these formats: https://github.com/Esri/projection-engine-db-doc   I've been trying to get the devs to start including the WKID in the string but no go for various reasons.
